# Metric and Convariant Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, tensors

> $g_{ij}$ is the metric tensor. Show that $g^{ij}$ which satsifies $g_{ij}g^{jk}=\delta_i^k$ is a covariant tensor of rank $2$.

I am not sure how to show this? Does it instead mean to show that $g_{ij}$ is a convariant tensor of rank $2$?

Comment: As you already said, $g_{ij}$ is a contravariant tensor of rank $2$. This means that $g_{ij}$ transforms in a certain way when changing coordinates. I assume, you know that. Now, the statement that $g^{jk}$ is a covariant tensor of rank $2$ means that it transforms in the "opposite" way to $g_{ij}$. What you have to show is that $g^{jk}$ indeed transforms in that "opposite" way. It is generally true that the inverse of a contravariant tensor of rank $2$ is a covariant tensor of rank $2$. You can either prove this general statement or the specific case with $g_{ij}$ or $g^{jk}$.

Comment: [continued] Basically, you have to do the following. Look up the definition of covariant and contravariant tensors and their transformations when changing coordinates. Make sure you understand the transformation of $g_{ij}$ under a change of coordinates from an initial coordinate system to a target coordinate system. Then, take the defintion of $g^{jk}$ in the initial coordinate system, transform it as if it was a covariant tensor, and convince yourself that the result is indeed $g^{jk}$ in the target coordinate system.

Comment: [continued] Then you will have shown that the inverse of the metric tensor transforms like a covariant tensor, which means it _is_ a covariant tensor.

Comment: @jflipp Thank you! So U pretty much have to show that inverse of a contravariant tensor of rank 2 is a covariant tensor of rank 2?

Comment: As i already said, your question is about the specific case of $g_{ij}$ and its inverse $g^{jk}$. You can prove the claim either for that specific case or for the general case. To me, the effort is virtually the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can take the equation
$$
g_{ij}g^{jk}=\delta_i^k
$$
as a *definition* of $g^{jk}$ and establish its transformation properties.

This (tensor) equation should be valid in any basis, so
$$
g'_{ij}{g'}^{jk}={\delta'}_i^k = {\delta}_i^k
$$

The change of basis formula for the covariant components is

$$
g'_{ij} = \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial x'_j} g_{pq}
$$

So in your new basis,
$$
\frac{\partial x_p}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial x'_j} g_{pq} {g'}^{jk} = {\delta}_i^k = g_{ij} {g}^{jk}
$$
or
$$
g_{pq}\left( \delta^p_{i}\delta^q_{j} g^{jk} - \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial x'_j} {g'}^{jk} \right) = 0 \\
\delta^p_{i}\delta^q_{j} g^{jk} = \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial x'_j} {g'}^{jk}
$$

Contracting both sides with $\delta^i_k$ and simplifying, you'll have

$$
g^{qp} = \frac{\partial x_p}{\partial x'_k}\frac{\partial x_q}{\partial x'_j} {g'}^{jk}
$$

You can always invert this by contracting both sides with $\dfrac{\partial x'_n}{\partial x_p}\dfrac{\partial x'_m}{\partial x_q} $ to get a more familiar form in which the coordinates after a change of basis are on the left hand side.

$$
{g'}^{mn} = \frac{\partial x'_m}{\partial x_q}\frac{\partial x'_n}{\partial x_p} g^{qp}
$$

which is the transformation law for the contravariant components of the 2nd order tensor.

Comment: Thank you very much! The change of basis is what confused me the most, but it's much more clear to me now. Thanks again!